# MYSQL.EXE and MYSQLINPORT.EXE input file? (Windows)

Tags: windows, mysql, restore, mysqlimport

Using MySQL on Windows, is there a way to specify the input file name when restoring using MYSQLIMPORT.EXE or MYSQL.EXE other than using < inputfile ?

For example, MYSQLDUMP.EXE has the --result-file (or -r) parameter. I cannot find an equivalent input file parameter for MYSQLIMPORT.EXE or MYSQL.EXE.

Is < inputfile the only way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is easy.  Just specify the input file as the last parameter of the command line, e.g.,

```
mysqlimport -uUser -p ... input.txt
```

Comment: It worked for me. At least with MySQL on Windows 5.5 and 5.7.

Comment: ah, sorry, I misread your answer. I thought you are using mysql.exe.

Answer (score 0):

This works: C:> mysql -e "source batch-file"

More here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/batch-mode.html